# Codechef Q - Why am I getting a "Wrong Answer"

Tags: python, algorithm

Sorry for the short title, SO won't let me post anything else.

I've written the following solution to the problem PHYSICS (http://www.codechef.com/problems/PHYSICS), it passes the simple test case provided but on submitting its results in WA(wrong answer) for all test cases.

```
import numbers

T = input()

for t in xrange(T):

N, F = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]
heights = [(long(i), False) for i in raw_input().split()]

heights.sort()
heights.reverse()

ways = 0
for i, h in enumerate(heights):
    height = h[0]
    used = h[1]
    if used:
        continue
    j = 0
    while True:
        force = F ** j
        if force > height:
            break
        bounce = height / force
        if isinstance(bounce, numbers.Integral):
            try:
                if len(heights) > i:
                    index = heights.index((bounce, False), i + 1)
                    if index != i:
                        heights[index] = (bounce, True)
                        ways += 1
                        break
            except ValueError:
                pass
            finally:
                j += 1
print ways
```

This is what I'm doing in my solution :

- for all the children in classroom heights list stores tuple(height,
  used) where height is the height of a child and boolean used
  indicates if child has been already used in forming a pair or not.
- the while loop checks if there's child whose height is equal to for all possible bounces

Help me spot the cases where this solution can fail, and the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the problem a bit wrong. You may use a child in more than one pair, the only special case is when two children have the same height. As a result you overcomplicate the solution a bit. Are you printing correct answer to example case 2? It seems that you will only count one pair with `4` while in fact it takes part in two pairs.